# How to fetch the scaling configuration of the secondary monitor?

Tags: c#, .net, dpi

I am trying to retrieve the scaling factor of the secondary display in order to scale the fonts of a windows application based on the monitor's scaling configuration. However, the current code that I have written fetches the scaling configs of the primary display only. Here is what my code looks like:

```cs
public static double GetScalingFactor()
{
    Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero);
    float dpiX;
    dpiX = graphics.DpiX;
    graphics.Dispose();
    // 96 dpi (dots per inch) correspond to 100% scaling, therefore, dividing by 96 gives the correct scaling factor.
    return dpiX / 96;
}
```

I feel like it has something to do with `IntPtr.Zero`, but I am not sure how to rectify the problem. Since it is not a `WinForms` or `WPF`, I cannot use `Form.Control.Handle`. Any leads in this regard would be great.

Comment: What OS are you using? On Windows you should use the [DPI-Awareness API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows).

Comment: Apologies for not mentioning it earlier, I am indeed using Windows 10.